# prevent sortable drop before first element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this situation

```
<ul>
 <li id="first">
    1
 </li>
 <li id="second">
    2
 </li>
 <li id="third">
    3
 </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to prevent dropping 2nd and 3rd LI element before 1st LI element, so in this situation only 2 and 3 should be swappable.
I managed to prevent dragging of first element with

```
.sortable({handle:"li",axis:"y","cancel":"#first"})
```

but that doesn't solve dropping element before first element in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify which items in your ul are sortable:

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
});
```

[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#items)

Comment: any chance of knowing how i can connect that to sortable?

Comment: The items property is included in the argument objects for sortable().

Using both examples, the final code would be (the cancel is no longer necessary):

.sortable({handle:"li",axis:"y", items: "li:not(#first)"})